# Is this bad practice in Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat

```
@Controller
public class View implements InitializingBean {

    @GetMapping("log")
    public String log() {
        return "log";
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("init");
    }
}
```

server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        autoDeploy="false" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">>
   <Context crossContext="true" debug="5" docBase="/data/project/chenshun-tag-test/code" path="" reloadable="false">
   </Context>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

When I deploy in tomcat 8.5.45 and afterPropertiesSet fails to execute, tomcat will start successfully, but the context start successfully. I can curl jsp and return 200. What I want is that tomcat fails to start, Is there a problem with my use or configuration?

ths in advance :)

```
➜  bin curl -I  127.0.0.1:18080/fix.jsp
HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5223231CAB44739BEAEB0BDEA879649F; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 27 Dec 2019 14:08:59 GMT

➜  bin curl -I  127.0.0.1:18080/view/1.json
HTTP/1.1 500
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: zh-CN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 27 Dec 2019 14:09:08 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: *but the context will not start successfully* - what do you mean?

Comment: @mentallurg  my expected goal that curl will return 404  but the result is  Servlet start failed and context start success.

Comment: @mentallurg so JspServlet is ok , curl xx.jsp is ok .   ths your comment

Answer (score 0):

Currently when a servlet with load-on-startup >=0 fails its startup, the context startup is still considered as OK.
With some webapps (like spring-based ones with a DispatcherServlet), this makes no sense at all : if the servlet failed its startup, the webapp is unuseable and it would be more sensible to have tomcat mark the context as failed.

refer https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56461